# Database: from listview to layout

Tags: android, database, listview

Ok. So I have gotten a part of my database (names of elements) to show up in a listview. I now want to be able to select one of those elements and pass the selection into a new fragment, calling the rest of the information from the database related to that element (ie atomic number, mass, melting point, etc.). How can I pass the selected element into my new fragment. Here is what I am currently trying:

```
private void selectElement(int position){

    elementFragment fragment = new elementFragment();
    fragment.loadElement(position);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

}
```

and then have it load the rest of the information related to it? Each entry in the database has a specific view that I wish to load it in, but am also willing to try to load it into a custom listview. (I'm going for a look relatively similar to the Google Music Play app when viewing an albums content)

Here is what I am playing with right now.

```
    public void loadElement(int position) {
    mPosition = position;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View viewElement = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_element_detail, container, false);

    Cursor c = myDB.getRow(mPosition);

    String name = DataBaseHelper.KEY_NAME;

    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]
            {DataBaseHelper.KEY_NAME, DataBaseHelper.KEY_ATOMIC_NUMBER, DataBaseHelper.KEY_ATOMIC_WEIGHT,
            DataBaseHelper.KEY_OXIDATION, DataBaseHelper.KEY_BOILING_POINT, 
            };

    elementName = (TextView) viewElement.findViewById(R.id.nameElement);
    elementName.setText(name);

    return viewElement;
}
```

I went ahead and removed some of the fields to help clean it up some.

One last error I am getting, is when I call the Cursor in my elementFragment, for some reason it continues to fail. Here is a copy of the logcat.

```
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at table.periodic.elementFragment.onCreateView(elementFragment.java:33)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1785)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:887)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1437)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
08-28 07:37:20.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1093):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The elementFragment.Java:33 corresponds to `Cursor c = myDB.getRow(mPosition);` in my code.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like `mDB` is `null`. Where are you initializing that?

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Do you mean where do I open the DB? I open it in a fragment called elementList and I load the name column from my DB into a listview. Its from a click on that listview that elementFragment is being called. I assume that since the DB has already been opened I don't need to call it again. I have added a openDB(); to elementFragment but notice no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple loadElement in your custom ElementFragment and call it after the fragment creation :

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Create fragment
    ElementFragment fragment = new ElementFragment();

    fragment.loadElement(position); // you might also want the id

    // start activity or launch fragment transition
    // then onCreateView will be probably called
    ...
}

public class ElementFragment extends Fragment {
    private int mPosition = -1;

    public void loadElement(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }
```

And just get the proper value in the onCreateView method :

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View viewElement = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_element_detail, container, false);

        Cursor c = myDB.getRow(mPosition);

        ...

        return viewElement;
    }
}
```

Edit : `Fragment fragment...` replaced by `ElementFragment fragment...`

Comment: Buzegg: Thank you for your response. I added the suggestions you gave, and am encountering a problem. When I call .loadElement(position), Eclipse is telling me "The method loadElement(int) is undefined for the type Fragment". See my code above as I have edited it.

Also, once I get my Cursor retrieving the correct row, how do I bind the information from that row to a textview? (I have about 20 columns to each row) And also see my cursor error I am getting. Thanks

Comment: @JoshuaSutherland Change the static type of `fragment` from `Fragment` to `ElementFragment` in the first line of `onListItemClick`.

Comment: You are right. I made an edit. About the binding, you started nice with fromFieldNames. Now you have to continue with an adapter : see the example in the doc : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html#Example

Comment: @MattiasBuelens got the elementFragment added and that fixed the .loadElement error. Thanks.

Comment: @buzeeg What you suggested is along the lines of what I did for my listview. But the textview that I am wanting to bind to is not part of a list. It is a textview in a normal layout. Is there a way to get it to bind to just a normal textview, or do I have to figure out a way to construct a listview that will allow for several unique rows?

Comment: Sorry, indeed I misunderstood. You just want to bind the element in your fragment layout?

Comment: @buzeeg Yes. My fragment calls an xml file for the layout. I need to bind information from the database then to an imageView and textView's inside that layout.

Comment: You need to create the layout, then find the view to bind, load the data from the DB and then copy the results to proper views.

Comment: @buzeeg Is there any tutorial anywhere or any example you can give me on how to do that? I have tried several different things and haven't been able to figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: Have a look here : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFragments/article.html#usingfragments_define This is basic Android development

Comment: @buzeeg Hey, so I have still been trying to get this thing to work for a while now and still can't figure it out. Is there anymore help that you can provide me? Thanks